# Could not run MongoDB server in Ubuntu system

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to run MongoDB in my Ubuntu machine using the following command but I am getting some error.

**Command:**

```
mongo
```

**Error:**

```
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017<br>
2019-12-23T17:00:38.815+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused<br>
2019-12-23T17:00:38.818+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :<br>
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13<br>
@(connect):1:6<br>
exception: connect failed
```

How can I resolve this issue and run MongoDB successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is caused because you didn't start mongodb service before you try starting mongo shell. You can check for a system service status. If it is failing because of some error try to fix it and start the process. Below are few things that might help with it.

Check if mongodb service is up and running

```
sudo systemctl status mongodb
```

If not start mongodb service on your ubuntu machine

```
sudo systemctl start mongodb
```

Start mongo shell

```
mongo
```